# Passing dimensions into flash in newsfeed

Tags: facebook, flash, feed

I am using newsfeed gaming to display interactive flash content within the newsfeed.

Up to last week both the newsfeed and timeline supported 398x398 px.

The timeline has been updated, and the new newsfeed is coming soon, meaning we need to support variants of size and dimension. At the moment these sizes are unconfirmed.

2 questions:

1. Can you pass the size of the flash into itself as it get written using og tags? I've tried apending strings ?size=x at the end of the url but the flash is sandboxed and can't read. There are flashvars variables present but we can't seem to access them
2. or, is it possible to use a fluid layout by setting the Flash movie parameters in the  tags to 100% and handle the logic for layout in the Flash movie?

   "og:video:scale" content="exactfit"
   "og:video:height" content="100%"
   "og:video:width" content="100%"

Then get the flash to query its on width / height on load.

Does anyone know how we can get this to work so that we can load in the correct layouts regardless of whether the flash is being viewed in the newsfeed or timeline?

with thanks, Dom